# USB HID device is grabbed by OS X Mojave at startup. How to avoid that?

Tags: macos, usb, hid, kernel-extension

I have a USB HID device (no mouse, no keyboard) that is grabbed by OS X Mojave at startup, when it is plugged in at startup. When I try to communicate with it (through libusb) I get the error that the device is busy until I unplug the USB device and replug it. After that it works fine.

When the USB device is not plugged in at startup and I plug it in just after starting it works also fine.

There is a signed codeless kext for it installed in /Library/Extentions.

All that behavior came up with Mojave. On all previous versions (El Capitan etc.) the problem did not occur. On the previous versions the kext was in /System/Library/Extentions. But that doesn't work at all on Mojave, so I moved it to /Library/Extentions with the result as described above.

Adding key "OSBundleRequired" with the value "Root" in the info.plist did not changed it and I'm running out of ideas.

This is the Info.plist used:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<!-- This is a dummy driver which binds to SG-LOCK.   It -->
<!-- contains no actual code; its only purpose is to     -->
<!-- prevent Apple's USBHID driver from exclusively      -->   
<!-- opening the device.                                 -->
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>English</string>
    <key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.domain.driver.dummy</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>KEXT</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1.0.0d1</string>
    <key>IOKitPersonalities</key>
    <dict>
        <key>USB Device</key>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
            <string>com.apple.kpi.iokit</string>
            <key>IOClass</key>
            <string>IOService</string>
            <key>IOProviderClass</key>
            <string>IOUSBInterface</string>
            <key>bConfigurationValue</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
            <key>bInterfaceNumber</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>idProduct</key>
            <integer>1000</integer>
            <key>idVendor</key>
            <integer>1000</integer>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Checking with ioreg in both cases gives the following output:

ioreg -lirc IOUSBHostDevice output right after boot w/o access:

```
+-o MyLock USB Key@14400000  <class IORegistryEntry:IOService:IOUSBNub:IOUSBDevice, id 0x10000033b, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (64 ms), retain 24>
  | {
  |   "sessionID" = 2407103480
  |   "USBSpeed" = 1
  |   "IOServiceLegacyMatchingRegistryID" = 4294968128
  |   "idProduct" = 4096
  |   "bDeviceClass" = 0
  |   "IOPowerManagement" = {"PowerOverrideOn"=Yes,"CapabilityFlags"=32768,"MaxPowerState"=2,"DevicePowerState"=2,"ChildrenPowerState"=1,"DriverPowerState"=0,"CurrentPowerState"=2}
  |   "bcdDevice" = 1
  |   "USB Product Name" = „MyLock USB Key"
  |   "AppleUSBAlternateServiceRegistryID" = 4294968128
  |   "locationID" = 339738624
  |   "bDeviceSubClass" = 0
  |   "kUSBCurrentConfiguration" = 1
  |   "IOCFPlugInTypes" = {"9dc7b780-9ec0-11d4-a54f-000a27052861"="IOUSBFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOUSBLib.bundle"}
  |   "bDeviceProtocol" = 0
  |   "USBPortType" = 0
  |   "USB Vendor Name" = „MyLock"
  |   "idVendor" = 1447
  |   "IOGeneralInterest" = "IOCommand is not serializable"
  |   "kUSBVendorString" = „MyLock"
  |   "IOClassNameOverride" = "IOUSBDevice"
  | }
  | 
  +-o AppleUSBHostLegacyClient  <class IORegistryEntry:IOService:AppleUSBHostLegacyClient, id 0x100000341, !registered, !matched, active, busy 0, retain 9>
  |   {
  |     "kUSBHostDeviceForceSuspend" = No
  |     "IOPowerManagement" = {"DevicePowerState"=0,"CurrentPowerState"=1,"CapabilityFlags"=65536,"MaxPowerState"=2,"DriverPowerState"=1}
  |   }
  |   
  +-o AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice  <class IORegistryEntry:IOService:AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice, id 0x100000346, !registered, !matched, active, busy 0, retain 4>
  |   {
  |     "IOProbeScore" = 50000
  |     "CFBundleIdentifier" = "com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice"
  |     "IOProviderClass" = "IOUSBHostDevice"
  |     "IOClass" = "AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice"
  |     "bDeviceSubClass" = 0
  |     "IOMatchCategory" = "IODefaultMatchCategory"
  |     "kUSBPreferredConfiguration" = 1
  |     "bDeviceClass" = 0
  |   }
  |   
  +-o IOUSBHostInterface@0  <class IORegistryEntry:IOService:IOUSBNub:IOUSBInterface, id 0x100000348, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (58 ms), retain 11>
    | {
    |   "USBPortType" = 0
    |   "IOCFPlugInTypes" = {"2d9786c6-9ef3-11d4-ad51-000a27052861"="IOUSBFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOUSBLib.bundle"}
    |   "bcdDevice" = 1
    |   "USBSpeed" = 1
    |   "idProduct" = 4096
    |   "bConfigurationValue" = 1
    |   "bInterfaceSubClass" = 0
    |   "locationID" = 339738624
    |   "IOGeneralInterest" = "IOCommand is not serializable"
    |   "IOServiceLegacyMatchingRegistryID" = 4294968137
    |   "IOClassNameOverride" = "IOUSBInterface"
    |   "AppleUSBAlternateServiceRegistryID" = 4294968137
    |   "idVendor" = 1447
    |   "bInterfaceProtocol" = 0
    |   "bAlternateSetting" = 0
    |   "bInterfaceNumber" = 0
    |   "bInterfaceClass" = 3
    | }
    | 
    +-o IOUSBHostHIDDevice@14400000,0  <class IORegistryEntry:IOService:IOHIDDevice:IOUSBHostHIDDevice, id 0x100000425, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (21 ms), retain 8>
      | {
      |   "IOClass" = "IOUSBHostHIDDevice"
      |   "Transport" = "USB"
      |   "BootProtocol" = 0
      |   "IOPersonalityPublisher" = "com.apple.driver.usb.IOUSBHostHIDDeviceSafeBoot"
      |   "HIDDefaultBehavior" = ""
      |   "MaxInputReportSize" = 23
      |   "IOProviderClass" = "IOUSBHostInterface"
      |   "Manufacturer" = „MyLock"
      |   "Product" = „MyLock USB Key"
      |   "DeviceUsagePairs" = ({"DeviceUsagePage"=65440,"DeviceUsage"=1})
      |   "IOProbeScore" = 50000
      |   "MaxOutputReportSize" = 23
      |   "ReportDescriptor" = <06a0ff0901a10109021580257f75089517810209031580257f750895179102c0>
      |   "IOUserClientClass" = "IOHIDLibUserClient"
      |   "bInterfaceSubClass" = 0
      |   "bInterfaceClass" = 3
      |   "IOCFPlugInTypes" = {"7DDEECA8-A7B4-11DA-8A0E-0014519758EF"="IOHIDFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOHIDLib.plugin","FA12FA38-6F1A-11D4-BA0C-0005028F18D5"="IOHIDFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOHIDLib.plugin"}
      |   "CountryCode" = 0
      |   "VendorID" = 1447
      |   "VersionNumber" = 1
      |   "IOMatchCategory" = "IODefaultMatchCategory"
      |   "CFBundleIdentifier" = "com.apple.driver.usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice"
      |   "PrimaryUsage" = 1
      |   "LocationID" = 339738624
      |   "ProductID" = 4096
      |   "Elements" = ({"ReportID"=0,"ElementCookie"=1,"CollectionType"=1,"Type"=513,"VariableSize"=0,"Elements"=({"VariableSize"=0,"UnitExponent"=0,"IsRelative"=No,"UsagePage"=65440,"Max"=127,"IsArray"=No,"Min"=18446744073709551488,"$
      |   "IOGeneralInterest" = "IOCommand is not serializable"
      |   "ReportInterval" = 8000
      |   "PrimaryUsagePage" = 65440
      |   "MaxFeatureReportSize" = 0
      |   "InputReportElements" = ({"ReportID"=0,"ElementCookie"=50,"Size"=184,"ReportCount"=1,"Type"=1,"VariableSize"=0,"UsagePage"=0,"ReportSize"=184,"Usage"=0})
      | }
      | 
      +-o IOHIDInterface  <class IORegistryEntry:IOService:IOHIDInterface, id 0x10000043e, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (6 ms), retain 6>
      |   {
      |     "MaxOutputReportSize" = 23
      |     "VendorID" = 1447
      |     "CountryCode" = 0
      |     "Product" = „MyLock USB Key"
      |     "VersionNumber" = 1
      |     "PrimaryUsage" = 1
      |     "LocationID" = 339738624
      |     "BootProtocol" = 0
      |     "ProductID" = 4096
      |     "DeviceUsagePairs" = ({"DeviceUsagePage"=65440,"DeviceUsage"=1})
      |     "Transport" = "USB"
      |     "ReportInterval" = 8000
      |     "ReportDescriptor" = <06a0ff0901a10109021580257f75089517810209031580257f750895179102c0>
      |     "HIDDefaultBehavior" = ""
      |     "PrimaryUsagePage" = 65440
      |     "Manufacturer" = „MyLock"
      |     "MaxFeatureReportSize" = 0
      |     "MaxInputReportSize" = 23
      |   }
      |   
      +-o IOHIDLibUserClient  <class IORegistryEntry:IOService:IOUserClient:IOHIDLibUserClient, id 0x1000004fb, !registered, !matched, active, busy 0, retain 6>
          {
            "DebugState" = {"EventQueueMap"=(),"Privileged"=Yes}
            "IOUserClientCreator" = "pid 86, loginwindow"
          }
```

ioreg -lirc IOUSBHostDevice output after replug with access:

```
+-o MyLock USB Key@14400000  <class IORegistryEntry:IOService:IOUSBNub:IOUSBDevice, id 0x1000006e5, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (3280 ms), retain 22>
  | {
  |   "sessionID" = 962218587513
  |   "USBSpeed" = 1
  |   "IOServiceLegacyMatchingRegistryID" = 4294969063
  |   "idProduct" = 4096
  |   "bDeviceClass" = 0
  |   "IOPowerManagement" = {"PowerOverrideOn"=Yes,"CapabilityFlags"=32768,"MaxPowerState"=2,"DevicePowerState"=2,"ChildrenPowerState"=2,"DriverPowerState"=0,"CurrentPowerState"=2}
  |   "bcdDevice" = 1
  |   "USB Product Name" = „MyLock USB Key"
  |   "AppleUSBAlternateServiceRegistryID" = 4294969063
  |   "locationID" = 339738624
  |   "bDeviceSubClass" = 0
  |   "kUSBCurrentConfiguration" = 1
  |   "IOCFPlugInTypes" = {"9dc7b780-9ec0-11d4-a54f-000a27052861"="IOUSBFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOUSBLib.bundle"}
  |   "bDeviceProtocol" = 0
  |   "USBPortType" = 0
  |   "USB Vendor Name" = „MyLock"
  |   "idVendor" = 1447
  |   "IOGeneralInterest" = "IOCommand is not serializable"
  |   "kUSBVendorString" = „MyLock"
  |   "IOClassNameOverride" = "IOUSBDevice"
  | }
  | 
  +-o AppleUSBHostLegacyClient  <class IORegistryEntry:IOService:AppleUSBHostLegacyClient, id 0x1000006e8, !registered, !matched, active, busy 0, retain 9>
  |   {
  |     "kUSBHostDeviceForceSuspend" = No
  |     "IOPowerManagement" = {"DevicePowerState"=0,"CurrentPowerState"=1,"CapabilityFlags"=65536,"MaxPowerState"=2,"DriverPowerState"=1}
  |   }
  |   
  +-o AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice  <class IORegistryEntry:IOService:AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice, id 0x1000006f4, !registered, !matched, active, busy 0, retain 4>
  |   {
  |     "IOProbeScore" = 50000
  |     "CFBundleIdentifier" = "com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice"
  |     "IOProviderClass" = "IOUSBHostDevice"
  |     "IOClass" = "AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice"
  |     "bDeviceSubClass" = 0
  |     "IOMatchCategory" = "IODefaultMatchCategory"
  |     "kUSBPreferredConfiguration" = 1
  |     "bDeviceClass" = 0
  |   }
  |   
  +-o IOUSBHostInterface@0  <class IORegistryEntry:IOService:IOUSBNub:IOUSBInterface, id 0x1000006f6, !registered, !matched, active, busy 0, retain 6>
      {
        "USBPortType" = 0
        "IOCFPlugInTypes" = {"2d9786c6-9ef3-11d4-ad51-000a27052861"="IOUSBFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOUSBLib.bundle"}
        "bcdDevice" = 1
        "USBSpeed" = 1
        "idProduct" = 4096
        "bConfigurationValue" = 1
        "bInterfaceSubClass" = 0
        "locationID" = 339738624
        "IOGeneralInterest" = "IOCommand is not serializable"
        "IOServiceLegacyMatchingRegistryID" = 4294969079
        "IOClassNameOverride" = "IOUSBInterface"
        "AppleUSBAlternateServiceRegistryID" = 4294969079
        "idVendor" = 1447
        "bInterfaceProtocol" = 0
        "bAlternateSetting" = 0
        "bInterfaceNumber" = 0
        "bInterfaceClass" = 3
      }
```

Comment: What does `sudo kextutil /Library/Extensions/<YourKextName>.kext` say? I suspect your problem might be kext signing, or do you have that aspect of SIP disabled?

Comment: It says: Warnings: 
    Personality CFBundleIdentifier differs from containing kext's (not necessarily a mistake, but rarely done): 
        USB Token

(kernel) Notice - new kext com.domain.driver.dummy, v1.0d1 matches prelinked kext but can't determine if executables are the same (no UUIDs). The notice comes from the other install path before. But that stuff has all been deleted. I checked also the status with code sign: codesign -vv /Library/Extensions/myusb.kext/
/Library/Extensions/myusb.kext/: valid on disk
/Library/Extensions/myusb.kext/: satisfies its Designated Requirement

Comment: Hmm, so it sounds like it's not a signing problem. Does `sudo kextcache -invalidate /` output any errors related to your codeless kext? This is what runs whenever `/Library/Extensions` changes, it bakes the kexts required for booting into a cache so the system doesn't have to scour the directory itself during early boot. So if the problem only occurs on boot, this is probably where it's going wrong. If that command on its own doesn't show anything, try `sudo kextcache -verbose 3 -invalidate /` - this should *definitely* mention your kext. Note: it takes a while to run.

Comment: kextcache -verbose 3 -invalidate / outputs: Adding /Library/StagedExtensions/Library/Extensions/SGLock.kext to prelinked kernel. I noticed also in the error log: cannot open file at line 42263 of [95fbac39ba] and: os_unix.c:42263: (2) open(/var/db/DetachedSignatures) - No such file or directory when I start accessing the USB Device.

Comment: Can you update your question with the subtree of your device from the output of `ioreg -lirc IOUSBHostDevice` when it's been claimed by the OS during boot (I.e. when your kext has failed to claim it) vs when you've hotplugged it (when your kext has taken it)?

Comment: I'm interested in the *subtree* of objects below the device, i.e. what clients etc. it has. That the device will be the same each time is expected.

Comment: I updated the ioreg output above - now including the subtrees for both cases. Now they are different, indeed.

Comment: I assume your Info.plist's `idVendor` and `idProduct` are not actually `1000` because those don't match the values for your device. Any other discrepancies between the real Info.plist and the one you posted?

Comment: Assuming your info.plist is otherwise identical, I'd perhaps try changing the `IOProviderClass` to `IOUSBHostInterface`. `IOUSBInterface` is the legacy name and only supported for backwards compatibility so perhaps support for that was removed during early boot in 10.14?

Comment: Direct hit! .... solved. Now the USB device is also accessible after boot without replugging. pmdj, thank you for your support!